# Environment variables on vimspector

Tags: python, plugin-vimspector

I'm using vimspector for debugging python, with debugpy. However, I need to source some environment variables before debugging in order for everything to work. How can I set up these env variables before debugging?

In VS code, I used to start the debug. The debug would break, but I could go into the debug terminal, source the env vars, and then it would work.

Comment: https://puremourning.github.io/vimspector/configuration.html#replacements-and-variables + https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#launch-with-options ?

Comment: Of course I read the documentation before resorting to asking it here. I couldn't find which field, on the json config file, I should use to setup the env variables. I tried some configs, but neither of them worked.

Comment: I did forget my customary welcome, so let me say: Welcome to [vi.se]! I added the doc links for you and for others; if you've seen them and tried to use them, perhaps you could [edit] your question to include something like "Based on link and link, I tried `XYZ` but it didn't work"? I tend to find that plugin questions are better answered by the plugin community, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions given by puremourning at https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/mbdt2e/environment_variables_on_vimspector/

I used a shell variable to run a script whose output is the JSON required for the env key; and type coercion to coerce this JSON string into the env map

It is illustrated in puremourning's example:

- shell variable: https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/blob/master/support/test/python/simple_python/.vimspector.json#L133-L136
- script: https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/blob/master/support/test/python/simple_python/make_env.sh
- env setting: https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/blob/master/support/test/python/simple_python/.vimspector.json#L147

Comment: I tried both keys `env` and `env#json` in the debug configuration for forwarding environment variables to binary executable, unfortunately neither of them works, my program still failed to retrieve env variables. What is your `vimspector` version ?