# Export environment variable to Vimspector

Tags: plugin-vimspector

I have some env vars set-up in my `.bashrc` but when I'm running Vimspector, those variables are not set-up. I want to export the env var when staring Vimspector, but I haven't managed to figure out how.

There is a relevant (almost same) question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/environment-variables-on-vimspector), but the answer is (probably) "expired", meaning that the links provided do not show that they were supposed to show, probably because the linked scripts have changed.

So, can anyone explain how to export an environment variable to Vimspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration section of the `.vimspector.json` that you use to define the debugging parameters of the VimSpector session there is a `env` section that you can use for that.

.vimspector.json

```
{
    "configurations": {
        "grr": {
            "default": false,
            "adapter": "debugpy",
            "breakpoints": {
                "exception": {
                    "raised": "N",
                    "uncaught": "Y"
                }
            },
            "configuration": {
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "cwd": ".",
                "python": "python.exe",
                "stopOnEntry": true,
                "console": "externalTerminal",
                "justMyCode": true,
                "debugOptions": [],

                "program": "grr.py",
                "args": ["--debug"],
                "env": { "foo" : "bar" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

grr.py

```
import os
print(os.environ["foo"])
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)